# How to zoom canvas based on parent container's height and width?

Tags: html, canvas, vuetify.js, fabricjs

I have been working on making canvas responsive, like adjusting it based on the screens.

Assume that i have a canvas of **1000 * 1000**, i am trying to zoom the canvas down to the parent card/contianer/div's height and width with a bit of padding.
[image]

**Approaches**

1.Css based approach - tried and it did work but the canvas quality reduced a bit.

```
         .lower-canvas {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            position: relative !important;  
        }
        .upper-canvas {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            position: absolute !important;
        }
        .canvas-container {
            width: 100% !important;
            height: auto !important;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }
```

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/GRryXym

But it seems like its not the right approach and canvas objects become distorted/blurry in smaller
screens.

2.Fabricjs based approach - Currently facing issue in this apporach

I am following the below steps to solve the problem.

- Get the wrapper v-card's height and width.
- Zoom the canvas based on fabricjsmethods.

```
let canvas = this.canvas;
const outerCanvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas-wrapper');
if (!outerCanvasContainer) return;
console.log(outerCanvasContainer, 'outerCanvasContainer');
const ratio = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
const containerWidth = outerCanvasContainer.clientWidth;
const scale = containerWidth / canvas.getWidth();
const zoom = canvas.getZoom() * scale;
canvas.setDimensions({
    width: containerWidth,
    height: containerWidth / ratio
});
canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Currently facing an issue in this approach it doesn't zoom to fit within the container instead it has the original dimensions i.e 1000*1000, not sure where am I going wrong any suggestions would be really helpful.

Current Codepen:**  https://codepen.io/adatdeltax/pen/BapmqPX

Comment: I struggled with this so much. I ended up using an `ActiveSelection` and then scaling that. Don't know if it will help in your case but here is my answer and code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66250265/840992 . My canvas is always the size of the window (set elsewhere) so I needed to scale if, for example, the user maximized the window and the aspect ratio changed. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks will try it.